# Change button size according to Screen width

Tags: html, css, width, screen-size

I have implemented a drop down list which contains text and an icon. I want to know how can I remove the text and keep the icon when the screen with is smaller (like max-width: 768 px). Is it possible to change the text of the div? Or I need to create another one and just show/hide both according to the screen width?

My code is:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">My List <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button
```

I want to remove the text and keep the icon.

Thank you!

Comment: Use media query and according to screen show icon or text. Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp or http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Comment: Is is possible to use the content property to change the content of my button? I just need to remove the text but keep the icon, I'm using font-awesome to display the icon. Can I replace the content with html code? (<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">GLOBAL AND REGIONAL SITES &nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button)

Answer (score 3):

No need to create another div, just use @media query and use css at which size of screen you want icon and and on which shize you want text.

Just wrap your text with tag.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><span>My List</span> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

and then css will be like;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  button span{
    display: none
  }
  button{
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My icon is displayed using font awesome, so can I just add content: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>' ?

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly. Except that i don't find a way to make the button smaller. I tried width: 10px; for example, but the width remains the same. How can I change the width of the button?

Comment: <button> has border, background color and box-shadow property. So you can't resize button using width: 10px; on <button> tag. So if you want to increase or decrease the width of button you have to use padding.