# How to increase the size of a bootstrap button as the window size decreases?

Tags: html, css, button, size, bootstrap-4

I am wondering how to increase the size of a bootstrap button as the window size reduces. I prefer the button to be small when the window is maximised however as the window size reduces i would like the button size to increase.

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Click Here To Enter</button>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998732/change-button-size-according-to-screen-width

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change button size according to Screen width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36998732/change-button-size-according-to-screen-width)

Comment: Post the code please